# Neo4j get multiple items with transactional HTTP endpoint

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get multiple items by a custom id with a cypher query in on the transactional HTTP endpoint, but the query returns no results. In the current example I have included only one id. If I run only the cypher query, with that specific id, I get a result, but when I try it with the transactional http endpoint, I get no results. What is wrong? Here is how the query looks when I try it in the console.

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {
    "statements": [{ "statement": "MATCH p WHERE p.id={props} return p;",
    "parameters": {"props": [{"id": "9fe2c276-3c94-43f9-bba3-9b3fd464f8da"}]}}],
    "resultDataContents": ["graph"]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referencing the `WHERE` wrong. If you sub in the properties like you have it, your query might look something like this when substituted:

```
MATCH p WHERE p.id='id:9fe2c276-3c94-43f9-bba3-9b3fd464f8da' return p
```

Try something like this:

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "MATCH (p) WHERE p.id IN {props} return p;",
      "parameters": {"props": ["9fe2c276-3c94-43f9-bba3-9b3fd464f8da"]}
    }
  ],
  "resultDataContents": ["graph"]
}
```

Basically props can be anything you want it to be, and here it is a JSON Array that contains a list of ID's, and you can use the `IN` clause of a `WHERE` to search for multiples.

Comment: I can't seem to get any results with this either.

Comment: I put each id  in its own statement/query instead, at least that works.

Comment: Okay, I see the issue with the above and I fixed it, it's because props is an array here, but you're asking for something that will work with a list of ids.

Comment: I have updated my code, it should work for single and multiples.